# Twilio error 63015 can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox , how do I fix that?

Tags: laravel, push-notification, twilio, twilio-php, twilio-programmable-chat

Im having a trouble using whatsapp notifications that says:
"Channel Sandbox can only send messages to phone numbers that have joined the Sandbox"

but in the page "**Twilio Sandbox for WhatsApp**", in **"participants"** shows my WhatsApp number, so I dont know what Im doing wrong..

**it has a table that shows my USERID: whatsapp+5545.*

[1st image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nksXD.png)

[2cond image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wUWbf.png)

Ive tried change the numbers from "

```
TWILIO_WHATSAPP_FROM
```

"

Comment: What code do you use the send the messages?

Comment: Hey Lucas, can you provide more details about your setup? Hopefully, they can help shed more light on what might be going wrong.